# Real-time image processing with Camera2

Tags: android, image-processing, android-image, android-bitmap

I tried searching in a ton of places about doing this, with no results. I did read that the only (as far as I know) way to obtain image frames was to use a ImageReader, which gives me a Image to work with. However, a lot of work must be done before I have a nice enough image (converting Image to byte array, then converting between formats - `YUV_420_888` to `ARGB_8888` - using RenderScript, then turning it into a Bitmap and rotating it manually - or running the application on landscape mode). By this point a lot of processing is made, and I haven't even started the actual processing yet (I plan on running some native code on it). Additionally, I tried to lower the resolution, with no success, and there is a significant delay when drawing on the surface.

Is there a better approach to this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure what exactly you are doing with the images, but a lot of times only a grayscale image is actually needed (again depending on your exact goal) If your camera outputs YUV, the grayscale information is in the Y channel. The nice thing,is you don't need to convert to numerous colorspaces and working with only one layer (as opposed to three) decreases the size of your data set greatly.

If you need color images then this wouldn't help

Comment: I am trying to perform skin tone segmentation and manipulation in native code, so a color image is needed.

Comment: yep, looks like my advice wont help much. Good luck